# How to generate a pseudorandom 32-byte string for use as a salt in a cryptographic hash function?

Tags: c++, hash, cryptography, salt

I am trying to code a password encryption function in C++ (Note: for educational purposes only. I won't actually be storing my passwords with it.) but I am not sure how to create a random 32-byte salt using a predefined characterset. How would I do this?

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void genSalt() {

    const char charset[] = {

        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        "!£$%^&*():@~#'?/><.,|`¬¦"

    };

}
```

The code should generate a random 32-byte string based on the defined character set 'charset'. I am not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you want to watch out for is the storage of some of those characters in the source file. Depending on encoding, `£`, `¬`, or `¦` could potentially be more than one byte, which can screw up your result; you should store those as hardcoded bytes if you want things to go smoothly regardless of encoding:

```
const char charset[] =
    "0123456789"
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    "!\xA3$%^&*():@~#'?/><.,|`\xAC\xA6";

// \xA3 = single-byte extended encoding for £
// \xAC = ¬
// \xA6 = ¦
```

(And by smoothly, I mean using those characters in your salt is a bad idea regardless, as they might conflict with other encodings where the salt is used.)

As for generating password salt, I'm no cryptologist, but it seems a little bit iffy to me to use anything other than a cryptographically secure psuedorandom number generator. If it's just a C++ exercise, the builtin random generators will be fine. I've never actually used the C++11 PRNG functions so this is a neat exercise for me too.

You start by making a `random_device` and then a randomizer engine:

```
#include <random>
std::random_device my_random_device;
std::default_random_engine my_random_engine(my_random_device());
```

There are different engines you can choose from for fine-tuning your random numbers, and default is an implementation defined selection (I assume that with this you can also easily plug in a cryptographically secure generator).

The `random_device` handles seeding automatically, whereas if you're using the older C-style `rand` function, you'd want to call `srand` with a seed (like the system time) to initialize it before generating anything.

To pick characters from your salt source, you select a distribution method, which you can get more details about here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

In this case, you want a uniform distribution across the set of salt characters:

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> random_number(0, sizeof(charset) - 1);
```

Which you can call as `random_number(my_random_engine)` to get a number between 0 and the last character index (don't forget to minus 1 to skip the null terminator).

And then with that it's easy to sample the characters and build a string:

```
std::string salt;
salt.reserve( 32 );
for( int i = 0; i < 32; i++ ) {
    salt.push_back(charset[random_number(my_random_engine)]);
}
std::cout << "salt result: " << salt << std::endl;
```

Working example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/mGd8pYP9Y3injuuG

---

One other thing I'd like to mention is the common pitfall of using `%` against a random number. For example, consider this test case using the older C-style `rand()` function:

```
int main() {
    // Seed randomizer
    srand( time(0) );

    // Print a random number between 0 and 1999
    int number = rand() % 2000;
    std::cout << number;
}
```

Usually people don't care, because it's "random enough", but you aren't going to get uniform distribution with modulus (`%`). `rand()` generates a number between `0` and `RAND_MAX`, and you should instead scale the range returned to fit your desired range.

```
// Sample random number between 0 and 1999. (add 1 to rand max to make 2000 not slightly possible)
int number = rand() * 2000 / (RAND_MAX+1)
```

Remember to pick an appropriate PRNG function to suit your needs as well, especially when looking for substantially difficult odds. If you're searching for 1 in 1 million, you may never find the result if the PRNG function doesn't uniformly cover the desired range.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `C++11` you can use `random_shuffle` to shuffle your array of elements and then always return the first `32` elements.

Something like the following should work for your case:

```
void genSalt() {
   static char charset[] = {
        "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!£$%^&*():@~#'?/><.,|`¬¦" };

    random_shuffle(begin(charset), end(charset));

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 32; i++)
       cout<<charset[i];
    cout<<endl;
}
```

*Please not that this approach does not return salt sequences with repetition. This is somehow ok for educational purpouses only as it works and it is easy to implement.*

---

Another approach would be to randomly pick elements from the sequence one by one as in the following:

```
void genSalt() {
    static const char charset[] = {
        "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!£$%^&*():@~#'?/><.,|`¬¦" };


    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
        cout<<charset[rand() % (sizeof(charset) - 1)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated in c++14, removed from C++17. Use `std::shuffle` (available since c++11) and a decently prepared prng.

Comment: @WhozCraig Good point. But the general idea is still valid. thanks